# A twist in Fibonacci's sequence in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am studyng recursion in Python and now I am having a problem with this exercise:

> Remember that Fibonacci's sequence is a sequence of numbers where every number is the sum of the previous two numbers.
>
> For this problem, implement Fibonacci recursively, with a twist! Imagine that we want to create a new number sequence called Fibonacci-3. In Fibonacci-3, each number in the sequence is the sum of the previous three numbers. The
>   sequence will start with three 1s, so the fourth Fibonacci-3
>   number would be 3 (1+1+1), the fifth would be 5 (1+1+3), the sixth would be 9 (1+3+5), the seventh would be 17 (3+5+9), etc.
>
> Name your function fib3, and make sure to use recursion.
>
> The lines below will test your code.
>
> If your function is correct, they will print **1**, **3**, **17**, and **57**.
>
> ```
> print(fib3(3))
> print(fib3(4))
> print(fib3(7))
> print(fib3(9))
> ```

This is the code until now:

```
def fib3(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return(fib3(n-1) + fib3(n-2) + fib3(n-3))
```

But the results are: 1, 2, 11, 37

Can you help me please to correct it?

Comment: `return 1` instead of `return n` within that first if-statement

Comment: @inspectorG4dget good catch!

Comment: I think you want that to be `if n <= 3 then 1`.

Comment: `fib3 = lambda n : 1 if n<=1 else fib3(n-1) + fib3(n-2) + fib3(n-3)`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description tells you why:

> The sequence will start with three 1s

Your solution, however only returns `1` for `n == 1` or lower:

```
if n <= 1:
    return n
```

This means that for `n == 2` (which should still return `1`), you'd instead return `fib3(2-1) + fib3(2-2) + fib3(2-3)`, or `fib3(1) + fib3(0) + fib(-1)`, which thanks to the above test, then bottoms out to produce `1 + 0 + -1` == `0`.

For `n == 3`, you'd return `fib3(2) + fib3(1) + fib3(0)`; we worked out above that `fib3(2)` is `0`, so the end result is `0 + 1 + 0` is the `1` you observed.

Finally, the 4th `fib3` number (`n == 4`), does not return 3, but `fib3(3) + fib3(2) + fib3(1)` == `1 + 0 + 1` == `2`.

Change that first test return `1` for `n <= 3`, to fix those first 3 values in the series:

```
def fib3(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib3(n-1) + fib3(n-2) + fib3(n-3)
```

Now the code passes the given tests:

```
>>> def fib3(n):
...     if n <= 3:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         return fib3(n-1) + fib3(n-2) + fib3(n-3)
...
>>> print(fib3(3))
1
>>> print(fib3(4))
3
>>> print(fib3(7))
17
>>> print(fib3(9))
57
```

Answer (score 1):

**The same thing other people are saying**

As others have noted, you have to return `1` when `n <= 3`

```
def fib3 (n):
  if n <= 3:
    return 1
  else:
    return fib3(n - 1) + fib3(n - 2) + fib3(n - 3)

print(fib3(3)) # 1
print(fib3(4)) # 3
print(fib3(7)) # 17
print(fib3(9)) # 57
```

**... but you can do better than that**

But that definition of `fib3` is junk. It does an *insane* amount of computation duplication. For example, `fib3(40)` takes **over 30 minutes** to compute due to O(n<sup>3</sup>) complexity

Consider an approach that uses an auxiliary loop with state variables – The O(n) complexity allows it to compute the same result in **less than a millisecond**.

```
def fib3 (n):
  def aux (n,a,b,c):
    if n == 1:
      return a
    else:
      return aux(n-1,b,c,a+b+c)
  return aux(n,1,1,1)

print(fib3(3))  # 1
print(fib3(4))  # 3
print(fib3(7))  # 17
print(fib3(9))  # 57
print(fib3(40)) # 9129195487
```

---

**Fibonacci as a generic program: `fibx`**

We can make generic the entire process of generating fibonacci sequences, but first we have to address something with your `fib3` function. In general, [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#List_of_Fibonacci_numbers) have a 0th term - ie, `fib(0) == 0`, `fib(1) == 1`. In your function, it looks like the first number is `fib3(1)`, where `fib3(0)` would produce an undefined result.

Below, I'm going to introduce `fibx` which can take any binary operator and any *seed* values and create any fibonacci sequence we can imagine

```
from functools import reduce

def fibx (op, seed, n):
  [x,*xs] = seed
  if n == 0:
    return x
  else:
    return fibx(op, xs + [reduce(op, xs, x)], n - 1)
```

Now we can implement standard fibonacci using `fibx` with the add (`+`) operator and seed values 0,1

```
from operator import add

def fib (n):
  return fibx(add, [0,1], n)

print(fib(0)) # 0
print(fib(1)) # 1
print(fib(2)) # 1
print(fib(3)) # 2
print(fib(4)) # 3
print(fib(5)) # 5
```

**Implementing `fib3` using `fibx`**

We can use the same `fibx` with the `add` operator to implement your `fib3` function, but because of your 1-based index, notice I'm offsetting `n` by 1 to get the correct output

```
from operator import add

def fib3 (n):
  return fibx(add, [1,1,1], n-1)

print(fib3(3)) # 1
print(fib3(4)) # 3
print(fib3(7)) # 17
print(fib3(9)) # 57
```

I'd recommend you start with a 0-based index tho. This means 0-based index `fib3(2)` is actually equal to your 1-based index of `fib3(3)`

```
from operator import add

def fib3 (n):
  return fibx(add, [1,1,1], n)

print(fib3(2)) # 1
print(fib3(3)) # 3
print(fib3(6)) # 17
print(fib3(8)) # 57
```

**Any imaginable sequence using `fibx`**

And of course you can make any other sequence you can imagine. Here we make `weirdfib` that uses multiplication (`*`) instead of addition (`+`) to combine terms and has a starting seed of `[1,2,3]`

```
from operator import mul

def weirdfib (n):
  return fibx(mul, [1,2,3], n)

print(weirdfib(0)) # 1
print(weirdfib(1)) # 2
print(weirdfib(2)) # 3
print(weirdfib(3)) # 6
print(weirdfib(4)) # 36
print(weirdfib(5)) # 648
print(weirdfib(6)) # 139968
```

Answer (score 0):

If `n <= 1`, the situation is a little more complex than just `return n`.

Consider the case of `n = 4`: your recursive call will be `fib(3)`, `fib(2)`, and `fib(1)`.

The lattermost returns 1 immediately, which is what you want. However, the two recursive calls do some weird things. `fib(2)` recurses into `fib(1)`, `fib(0)`, and `fib(-1)`, the return values for which basically hand back a big fat 0. `fib(3)` recurses into `fib(2)` (which we saw is 0), `fib(1)` (which works, and is 1), and `fib(0)` (which is also 0).

Hence, you get the 1 from the very beginning, and the 1 from the recursed `fib(1)` component of `fib(3)`. There's your 2!

Basically, you want to make sure your base case can't return a negative number. Fix that (return either 1 or 0), and you should be good. As [Martijn Pieters mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43711312/13604), you can also make your base case `n <= 3` and it should achieve the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

Let me contribute with perhaps the most optimal "pythonic" answer.

The main point is to avoid recursive function calls to optimise the efficiency of the code. Pythonic way of thinking would involve the following compact code, which is an iterative creation of the Fibonacci sequence of n numbers, including the seed numbers [1, 1, 1].

```
def fibonacci_sequence(n):
    x = [1, 1, 1]
    [x.append(x[-1] + x[-2] + x[-3]) for i in range(n - len(x))]
    return x

import time
n = int(raw_input("Enter the size of Fibonacci-3 sequence: "))
start_time = time.time()
print fibonacci_sequence(n)
print "The time to compute the Fibonacci-3 sequence is: %s" % (time.time() - start_time)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I really like this answer, but you might want to avoid remarks like "most optimal" – *especially* without writing anything to back them up. I'm not trying to say "my answer is faster than yours" – I just mean you should be cautious when opening such broad topics in your answers. My answer *does* use recursion and runs faster than this iterative list comprehension. My *only* point in saying so is that it refutes this idea that recursion is inherently slow or non-optimal in all cases. As for *why*, I suspect the 3 array lookups per iteration has something to do with it.

Comment: tldr: try to stick to objective descriptions in your answers. when opinions are offered, provided extended explanations and/or reasoning.